# C++, How to Ensure Aligned Memory Using mmap()?

Tags: c++, memory, malloc, cpu, mmap

I am currently allocating memory using mmap like this:

```
void *void_new_block = mmap(nullptr, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

Now I want to improve performance on 64 bit cpus thus I need my block to reside between addresses which are multiplication of 8 For that I need 2 things:

1. To ensure that size is a multiplication of 8 (which I already did by rounding it up)
2. To ensure that mmap will start allocating at an addresses of multiplication of 8.

How may I solve 2? I heard that some special flag might help?

Some Notes, My OS:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

g++ version:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: Over allocate and then adjust the returned pointer to meet the alignment needs.

Comment: @RichardCritten but then how can I know from where to do munmap?

Comment: I would prefer a solution where providing some flag will solve 2, one day I read it's possible but can't find it anymore

Comment: Don't adjust the return pointer, copy it then align it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mmap always allocates entire pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html).

> If addr is NULL, then the kernel chooses the (page-aligned) address at which to create the mapping [...] If addr is not NULL, then [...] on Linux, the kernel will pick a nearby page boundary

(on systems other than Linux, it still has to pick a page boundary, but it might not be nearby)

On x86 or x86_64, pages are 4096 bytes, so you are fine. It is hard to imagine a CPU with pages smaller than 8 bytes.

Comment: So you are 100% sure it will allocate correctly

Comment: @daniel Yes. Pages are bigger than 8 bytes. Actually 4096 is on the small side; some other CPUs have even bigger pages. Since they are multiples of 4096 bytes they're already multiples of 8 bytes.